# CSS: How to show color picker in dropdown or select?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I am using Vue.js (which I don't think have anything to do with this issue) and a color picker package [vue-color](https://github.com/xiaokaike/vue-color). What I want to achieve is following:

A button or rectangle element have color as selected color when clicked show a menu type dropdown with color picker. User can pick color here, and when they click outside color picker, it collapse. I tried doing this with bootstrap `dropdown` and everything works fine except when I click to pick color the menu collapse(refer to following code):

```
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#"><sketch-picker v-model="colors" /></a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Above code shows this output, which is same as what I want to achieve but on first click only it collapse, hence user couldn't tune it.

On exploring I found below link, but am not able to translate it into vue.js
https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/1490

I also tried using `select` and putting color-picker in it's `option`, but then no color-picker comes and only r, g, b values are shown.

I also tried to make my own div and show-and-hide using vue. But instead of coming over base div it takes it own space even with `z-index` (I know this is workable but I couldn't get this working). Any help would be appreciated

Comment: A workaround is to disable the dropdown item container for the color picker ([demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/zkxx28p8rm)). Not the best solution (especially for accessibility), but it might just work well enough for you.

Comment: Great ! This looks working. I am trying to implement your solution without bootstrap-vue but it isn't working. I think your solution is bootstrap specific but not vue, hence it should work `<ul>
      <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li class="disabled" ><sketch-picker v-model="colors" /></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>`

Comment: I got a solution ! By using vue preventDefault() and stopPropogation(). In my dropdown menu I did this `<li v-on:click.stop.prevent="changeColor"><sketch-picker v-model="colors" /></li>`

Comment: Glad you got that working :) Interestingly enough, using those same event modifiers (along with `.native`) on `<sketch-picker>` itself ([demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/zkxx28p8rm)) is another solution